# Using the isdirty() to auto increment the field which is not a primary key

Tags: postgresql, grails, groovy

I have a domain class `Enquiry` where a primary key `id` is auto generated. I have `enquiry_no` which is not a primary key but I want to make it a unique and an auto increment field which I need to display in my gsp page.

I have been through the grails documentation but cant find a way where we make a non primary key auto increment.

Please suggest me a way to solve this issue.

As suggested by the answers I tried the following code in my domain class Enquiry but its not working still ??

```
    def beforeUpdate() {
     "in before update method"println
     Enquiry enquiry=Enquiry.get(1)

    if(enquiry.isDirty()==true) {
        enquiryNo += 1
    }

}
```

Comment: it may be tricky.. but how about reusing.. id value in enquiry_no

Comment: Surely that should be trivial? In SQL, it's just a field of `SERIAL` type - or a field like `integer DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')` with a `CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;`. Then add a `UNIQUE (columname)` constraint, or a `UNIQUE` index...

Comment: I wrote the following code but  in my gsp page the field for enquiryno is not geting incremented .                                   def beforeUpdate() {

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own approach via GORM's [`beforeUpdate`](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping), although keep in mind updates outside of the application will not trigger this ([Craig Ringer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer) comment should suffice for that, though):

```
class Enquiry {
    //...
    def beforeUpdate() {
        enquiry_no += 1// Or whichever value you need
    }
}
```

Might want to limit access to `enquiry_no` too if you aren't already.